# How to Redux connect store to an async Redux action

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux

I have an async action `fetchTasks` which is given a list of tasks, and sends a request for each task (these may or may not take a while to finish). I want my front end to only be able to send 5 requests at a time. Since many components have Ajax functionality, I decided to implement the request counter within the redux store. The value is called `fetchCount`, and is used by many components to see if they want to allow the user to send a request.

Now the issue is `fetchTasks` can get more than 5 tasks in the task list. I've dealt with that by first sending requests until the `fetchCount` reaches 0, then I recursively call `fetchTasks` whenever a server response is received for a fetch.

```
function fetchTasks(taskList){
    return dispatch => {
         while(taskList.length > 0 && fetchCount > 0){ // <-- I need fetchCount to be up to date with the store
           decrementFetchCount(); //a redux action
           let task = taskList.pop();
           $ajax({
               url: `/do/${task}`,
               success:(data)=>{
                 processData(data); // redux action
                 incrementFetchCount(); // a redux action
                 dispatch(fetchTasks(taskList));
                } 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that I need `fetchTasks` to be aware of the value of `fetchCount` at any point in its run time. I'm thinking that connecting it to the store is the key, but I don't know how to connect a function to the store. Therein lies the problem.
Also, this smells. If someone has an alternative way to implement this that they want to suggest, that would also be a valid answer.

Comment: Don't do this on the client side if you want it to be safe against manipulations by the user at all. Any code executed on the client can be changed arbitrarily by the user.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'm not worried about that, this is only an internal tool. Thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is using `redux-thunk`. You can have a second paramenter `getState` together with `dispatch`.

You `fetchTasks` would look something like this...

```
function fetchTasks(taskList) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        while (taskList.length > 0 && getState().fetchCount > 0) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Indeed I'm using `redux-thunk`. Didn't know you can include a `getState` parameter!